# Generating and Displaying PDF file in Flex/Java

Tags: java, apache-flex, pdf, pdf-generation, jasper-reports

We have Flex on the front end and Java on the back end. When a user will request for a PDF file, request will go to the Java backend, where a PDF file will be generated using Jasper Reports. What we dont know is how to display this PDF file in browser; since we dont want to use JSP/Servlets etc - It has to be flex only. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you communicating between Flex and Java now?

Answer (score 1):

Flash Player cannot natively render PDF files. This is possible using Adobe AIR but not in a Flex application. Your best bet is to call navigateToURL() and open a Servlet in a new browser tab/window. The Servlet can simply write contents of the PDF file to the OutputStream and set the appropriate HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

i think this question is old, but it may help others, there's a new library developed by Jasper Forge them selves, which deals with JasperReports directly, i mean it's not a PDF viewer, but a JasperReport exporting tool, you can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports-flash/)

i tried it through using [JasperServer](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperserver), when viewing reports you can choose from different options to export it, one of them is flash, and it's working nice

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, PDFs don't always display in the browser.  It depends on the user's settings.  You essentially header them the pdf file and either they download it or a program like Acrobat Reader opens in the browser to display it.

Not sure how this is done in flex, I would imagine if you're using Java one simple servlet could do it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant that only, may be it was not clear.
With Servlets it's simple, but we want to avoid that for reasons unknown to me :)